# Empty return of NodeJS in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, xmlhttprequest

My NodeJs application return in this url (http://localhost:3000/api/campaigns) a json response.

But when my Angular application call this url, get a empty response.
I try to change the `200` http code to `404`, and I see this change, but always there ara a empty response.

Angular:

```
var campaigns = function(country) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get( "http://localhost:3000/api/campaigns" ).then(function(response) {
    deferred.resolve(response);
  }, function(response) {
     deferred.reject(response);
  });
  return deferred.promise
}
```

And in my NodeJs code:

```
exports.findAllCampaigns = function(req, res) {

  Campaign
    .find({})
    .limit(10)
    .exec(function(err, campaigns) {
        if(err) res.send(500, err.message);

        res.status(200).jsonp(campaigns);
    });

};
```

In my browser console, the `XHR request` is always empty (`http 200`).

[image: Browser net console]

Comment: its `jsonp` call? then why you are making `.get` call. I think you should do `$http.get` with `params` of `callback: JSON_CALLBACK`

Comment: shouldn't it be `res.send(campaigns)` or `res.send(JSON.stringify(campaigns))` with correct content type header? or is jsonp a wrapper for that?

Comment: I try to change `jsonp` to `send`. Returns the same empty response, but changing the header content-type = "application/json" to "text/html"

Comment: Just implement CORS in api

Comment: Thanks! I just enabled the cors middleware with: `var cors = require('cors')`
`var app = express()`
`app.use(cors())`

Answer (score 0):

This is just to have a response on this question (i would like that either charlietfl or Carlos Vazquez posted this as response rather than me :) )

BY charlietfl --> Just implement CORS in api

BY Carlos Vázquez --> Thanks! I just enabled the cors middleware with:

`var cors = require('cors');
 var app = express();
 app.use(cors());`